# Enabling multidex creating singledex when min sdk is 5.0 below but mutiple dex when min sdk is 5.0 and above

Tags: android, gradle, android-5.0-lollipop, android-multidex

Enabling multidex creating singledex when min sdk is 5.0 below
But It is creating mutiple dex files when min sdk is 5.0 and above.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create project and add `appcompat` and RecyclerView libs
2. set min sdk as 14  and build the project
   **output:** single dex will be created in build folder
3. set min sdk as 21  and build the project
   **output:** multiple dex files will be created in build folder

Is there any way to avoid creating multiple dex when 64k limit is not reached in 5.0 and above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable InstantRun to disable multidex because it's automatically configured if your minimum sdk is set to 21 or higher.

You can read it from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-on-l):

> **Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**
>   Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading multiple DEX files from APK files. ART performs pre-compilation at app install time which scans for classesN.dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for execution by the Android device. Therefore, if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher, you do not need the multidex support library.
>
> For more information on the Android 5.0 runtime, read ART and Dalvik.
>
> Note: While using **Instant Run**, Android Studio automatically configures your app for multidex when your app's `minSdkVersion` is set to **21** or higher. Because Instant Run only works with the debug version of your app, you still need to configure your release build for multidex to avoid the 64K limit.